# Downloading files using Adobe AIR

Tags: download, air

When I download a file using URLStream and write to a file using FileStream, where else do the file gets cached? It definitely gets cached somewhere, as the second time I try to download the same file, it comes down like a lighting..

Answer (score 2):

AIR is using the operating systems networking stack for this, so the cache location will depend on where the OS caches files.

On Windows, check the Internet Explorer settings, on Mac check Safari. Im not sure about Linux.

mike chambers